# Excel spread sheet if statement

Tags: excel, if-statement

I'm working on an excel spreadsheet and want an if statement in a cell that allows user input if a certain condition is met, and calculates a value otherwise.  Something like

```
=if(condition true, whatever user wants, 5*$A$1,)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What's the condition?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to have the user-input in the same cell as your formula. (without using VBA)

To do it without VBA you will need to use at least 2 cells, one with your formula, and one for the user value

There are a couple of ways you can do it with VBA

Heres a simple one, but would not really recomment it, if lots of cells use this it you'll get lots of inputboxes!

usage: `=IF(condition, UserInput(), false result)`

```
Public Function UserInput() As Integer ' used integer as an example
Dim Result As Variant

    Result = Application.InputBox("Enter an Integer", "Input Required", , , , , , 1) ' inputbox, the final 1 makes it only accept numbers
    If VarType(Result) = vbBoolean Then
        UserInput = 0 ' the default value
    Else
        UserInput = CInt(Result) ' make sure its an integer
    End If
End Function
```

Another one, would involve using the selection change and cell change events to read the initial value of the cell being changed, and allow the change (adding the value into the initial formula's "true" block or deny the changes by reverting the cells formula to the initial one.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use a Macro to update only null columns or you need to allow user to enter values in another column and then merge the values in this column, third option is to fill it with formulas and allow people to edit it to any value if they want only values

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(C11="Economic",120,IF(C11="DBServer",480,IF(C11="Gamer",120,IF(C11="Custom",M15,"null"))))
```

My example was to build an optimal computer given certain constraints.  There was a drop down with `Economic`, `DBServer`, `Gamer`, and `Custom` as options.  If you chose economic, then 120 would show up in the cell, DbServer meant 480, etc.  If you selected custom, then it would refer to cell M15 which was a user input that didn't affect the code of the cell you wanted the final number  in.